# Area growth of harmonic functions

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

Can one construct a harmonic function $f$ defined in unit disk with condition $f(0)\geq1$ such that area of $\{z\in\mathbb{D}: f(z)>0\}$ is small enough?

Comment: $f$ is real-valued? The question is $\forall\epsilon>0$ $\exists f$ harmonic s.t. area$(\cdots)<\epsilon$?

Comment: Small enough for what?

Comment: meaning for $\epsilon>0$ we want to find harmonic function $f$ such that $f(0)\geq 1$ and $area(\{z\in\mathbb{D}: \,f(z)>0\})\leq \epsilon$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question was asked and answered at [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/q/185423/55893).
The point of this answer is to provide the link and remove this from the list of unanswered questions.
(I made this answer community wiki so that I don't gain reputation when I have not earned it and anyone can freely add details.)